# android writing files from onSensorChanged event

Tags: android

I confess I'm a bit stumped on this one. I've just started with Android programming and am loving the experience so far, but I've got a mysterious problem where I write to files but they remain indefinitely empty (no, I'm pretty sure I'm not overwriting them accidentally).

The scenario is that I'd like to record a few seconds of sensor data to a log file on the SD card upon hitting a button. I also display the same content to the screen. However, though the content that appears on the screen is correct, the log file gets created but is empty.

I can only assume that it has something to do with the fact that I'm calling write from the onSensorChanged(Event) method, since the same code executes just fine when used elsewhere.

```
public MyClass(....){
    ....
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Thread.sleep(time * 1000);
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    try {
        logWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    String msg = msgFor(event);
    try {
        logWriter.write("SOME_TEXT" + msg + "\n"); // FileWriter logWriter is a field, but the file is empty in the end
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    resultBox.append("\n" + msg); // TextView resultBox is a field, and writes to screen correctly
    Log.d("SENSOR-CHANGE", msg);
}

private String msgFor(SensorEvent event){
    return event.timestamp+", "+event.sensor.getName()+", "+Arrays.toString(event.values);
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I am aware that there are some similar threads out there, but I didn't find exactly what I needed.

Comment: what is error you are getting man

Comment: there is no error message, but the file is empty. However, the 'resultBox' on the screen fills up with text.